# Is studying computer games legal in correspondence chess?

Tags: opening, engines, correspondence-chess

I have recently umm downloaded the Dragon Cookbook from Chessbase. It is filled with human and computer games in the dragon. The thing is, are previously played computer games allowed to be seen in correspondence chess?

Comment: "Correspondence chess" is not a single entity, every competition / federation / website has its own rules, and this part differs.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Online correspondence chess, I believe chess.com rules apply everywhere.

Comment: @MikhailTal Chess.com rules apply at chess.com. Other places have their own rules, and there (perhaps unfortunately) is no reason to believe that this kind of sublteties would be the same everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

On chess.com, use of books and game databases is allowed. Use of engines and tablebases is not. Your book is either a book or a game database and therefore fine.

There are also sites that don't allow any outside help (no books, no databases), and on the other hand the ICCF (the offiical FIDE-affiliated Correspondence Federation that is also completely online nowadays) does allow engine use, so it's best to always check the rules of the actual site you're using.

Comment: What is a tablebase?

Comment: A database that contains all endgame positions up to a certain number of pieces (usually 6 including kings), and their results. With a tablebase you can play such positions perfectly. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame_tablebase

Answer (score 2):

It is not illegal to view and use previously played Chess games, some people even use Chess Analyse programs while playing on (for example) the internet. However most websites do not allow you to use programs to gain benefits over other players, including but not limited to analyzers.

Ofcourse it is allowed to study previously played Chess games, you can even learn a lot from them!